# asyncio ftp push from 1 client to n servers simultaniously in parallel

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I tried "everything" but with no luck... probably am I misusing/misunderstanding asyncio.

**[my goal/use case]**

Push games from 1 computer (1Gb nic) to 16 xboxs (100Mb nic) in chunks of 10 (to take advantage of the 1:10 bandwidth ratio)

**[my problem]**

My code runs synchronously on a per-file/per-host basis:

- File1 pushed to xbox1... then xbox2...
- then File2 pushed to xbox1... then xbox2

**[testing setup]**

- 1 FTP client
- 1 FTP server with 2 ≠ users

**[my code]**

The main challenge I think I am facing is with the `ftp_push` function looping over itself and dealing with await.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import os
from ftplib import FTP
from tqdm import tqdm

game_dir = "~/360/Games/halo_3"
ftp_host = os.environ['ftp_host']
ftp_pass = os.environ['ftp_pass']
ftp_users = ["xbox1", "xbox2"]

def get_dir_size(path: str) -> int:
  """
  return path size in bytes
  """
  if not os.path.isdir(path):
    print(f"Error: {path} is not a directory")
    exit(1)
  size = 0
  with os.scandir(path) as x:
    for entry in x:
      if entry.is_file():
        size += entry.stat().st_size
      elif entry.is_dir():
        size += get_dir_size(entry.path)
  return size

async def ftp_login(host, user, passwd):
  ftp = FTP(host)
  ftp.login(user=user, passwd=passwd)
  print(ftp.getwelcome())
  return ftp

async def ftp_push(ftp_tqdm, path):
  ftp = ftp_tqdm[0]
  tqdm = ftp_tqdm[1]
  with os.scandir(path) as x:
    for entry in x:
      if entry.is_file():
        ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {os.path.basename(entry.path)}', open(entry.path, 'rb'), 2048, callback = lambda sent: tqdm.update(len(sent)))
      if entry.is_dir():
        ftp.mkd(os.path.basename(entry.path))
        ftp.cwd(os.path.basename(entry.path))
        await ftp_push(ftp_tqdm, entry.path)
        ftp.cwd('..')
  await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
  dir_size = get_dir_size(game_dir)
  # create FTP instances (1 per xbox)
  ftps_tasks = await asyncio.wait([ftp_login(ftp_host, ftp_user, ftp_pass) for ftp_user in ftp_users])
  ftps = [i.result() for task in ftps_tasks for i in task]
  # create TQDM instances (1 per xbox)
  tqdms = [tqdm(unit = 'B', unit_scale = True, leave = False, miniters = 1, desc = ftp_suer, total = dir_size) for ftp_suer in ftp_users]
  # zip FTP & TQDM instances
  ftps_tqdms = list(zip(ftps, tqdms))
  # trigger ftp push
  await asyncio.wait([ftp_push(ftp_tqdm, game_dir) for ftp_tqdm in ftps_tqdms])


if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

How to make this code push data in //?

Thank you for your precious help!
Cheers!

Comment: Well I think the function which is actually pushing the data is `ftp.storbinary`, right? It is not async. You have to use functions (or create on your own) which make use of asyncio when actually sending or receiving data.

Comment: Hi @lord_haffi,
Thank you for your help.
You are right about `ftp.storbinary`. I tried putting it async but it didn't work.

I totally changed strategy using threads and it works (see new message below). Still, I feel defeated against async ;-)

Comment: You cannot "put it async". I just looked up ftplib and on the first sight it didn't seem to support asyncio. The library has to support it, because the code must have a "hook" to the asyncio event loop at the time, when the request ist actually send through the FTP. You can think of it as "giving free the CPU time to do other things". Threads do work because they are executed quasi-parallel statement-wise. I.e. the scheduling is fully controlled by the framework. With `asyncio` the respective functions control the scheduling by use of `Future` objects e.g..

Comment: If you want to use `asyncio` you have to use a library which supports it. E.g. [aioftp](https://pypi.org/project/aioftp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solved]

Hi,

Again thank you @lord_haffi for taking the time to answer. I ended up changing strategy using Python threads.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import json
from live_xboxs import LiveXboxs
from ftp import Ftp
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from toolbox import Toolbox
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

def starmap_ftp_push(ftp, path, xbox_tqdm, dir_tqdm):
  with os.scandir(path) as x:
    ls = ftp.nlst()
    for entry in x:
      if entry.name in ls:
        print(f"{xbox_tqdm.desc} => {entry.name} ({os.path.basename(path)}) exists in {ftp.pwd()}")
      else:
        if entry.is_file():
          ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {os.path.basename(entry.path)}', open(entry.path, 'rb'), 2048, callback = lambda sent: Toolbox.tqdm_update(xbox_tqdm, dir_tqdm, sent))
        if entry.is_dir():
          ftp.mkd(os.path.basename(entry.path))
          ftp.cwd(os.path.basename(entry.path))
          starmap_ftp_push(ftp, entry.path, xbox_tqdm, dir_tqdm)
          ftp.cwd('..')

def push_games(Ftps, live_xboxs):
  """
  Ftp push games in // to all alive xbox (chunks of max 10 xboxs)
  """
  print(f" push games to {GAMES_CWD}")
  threads = len(live_xboxs) if len(live_xboxs) <= 10 else 10
  with ThreadPool(threads) as pool:
    games_size = sum([Toolbox.get_dir_size(game) for game in GAMES])
    xbox_tqdms = [tqdm(unit = 'B', unit_scale = True, leave = False, miniters = 1, desc = xbox['name'], total = games_size, position = idx) for idx, xbox in enumerate(live_xboxs)]
    for game in GAMES:
      # Create tqdm instance (1 per game)
      game_size = Toolbox.get_dir_size(game)
      dir_tqdm = [tqdm(unit = 'B', unit_scale = True, leave = False, miniters = 1, desc = f"{xbox_tqdm.desc}/{game}", total = game_size, position = idx) for idx, xbox_tqdm in enumerate(xbox_tqdms, start=(len(xbox_tqdms)+1))]
      # Create a list of 1 game_dir the size of the ftps & tqdm lists
      game_path = [game for x in live_xboxs]
      ftps = [ftp.ftp for ftp in Ftps]
      args = list(zip(ftps, game_path, xbox_tqdms, dir_tqdm))
      [Ftp.ftp.cwd(GAMES_CWD) for Ftp in Ftps]
      pool.starmap(starmap_ftp_push, args)

# FTP login to each xbox
Ftps = [Ftp(xbox['ip'], xbox['name']) for xbox in live_xboxs]
# Push games
push_games(Ftps, live_xboxs)
```

Comment: Still this is not 100% optimal as I call pool.starmap for each game.
Doing so means ftp push game_2 will not start until game_1 is pushed on all xboxs